# How to include different css file dynamically with asset pipeline in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I am upgrading to rails 3.1. in my old application.html.erb, I have a line of this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "themes/#{session[:theme].nil? ? 'base' : 
     session[:theme]}/ui.all" %>
```

As you know, I want to change the style base on the session[:theme].
Thanks to [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448838/how-can-i-dynamically-require-assets-in-the-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline), I made a little progress. I modified my `application.css.erb` to this:

```
/*
* *= require_self
* */
<%
    require_asset("themes/#{session[:theme].nil? ? 'base' : 
                    session[:theme]}/ui.all" )
k%>
/* rest of file omitted */
```

But it complains this:

```
undefined local variable or method `session' for #<#<Class:0x95152e4>:0x9c6c8bc>
 (in /home/rocky/work/apps/fanfan/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.erb)
```

Answer (score 2):

The application manifest is compiled at deploy time, or compiled and cached if you are serving assets live, so you have two problems.

The first is that there is no session value available, and the second is that the even if you could change this it won't work; it would be cached the first time the manifest is compiled.

You can go back to your initial solution, and make one addition to your config for it to work.

```
config.assets.precompile += ['themes/theme1_name/ui.all', 'themes/theme2_name/ui.all', etc]
```

I am assuming here that `themes` is in the default stylesheets location.